# Fedora 22: ERROR: No module named '_rpmb' while building docker

Tags: python, docker, fedora

I am trying to build docker on Fedora 22 using mock/scm integration. The error I am getting here is:

```
DEBUG: Preparing SCM sources
ERROR: No module named '_rpmb'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/mock", line 829, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mockbuild/trace_decorator.py", line 84, in trace
    result = func(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/sbin/mock", line 650, in main
    run_command(options, args, config_opts, commands, buildroot, state)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mockbuild/trace_decorator.py", line 84, in trace
    result = func(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/sbin/mock", line 663, in run_command
    (options.sources, options.spec) = scmWorker.prepare_sources()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mockbuild/trace_decorator.py", line 84, in trace
    result = func(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mockbuild/scm.py", line 134, in prepare_sources
    rpm_spec = ts.parseSpec(self.spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/rpm/transaction.py", line 40, in parseSpec
    import _rpmb
ImportError: No module named '_rpmb'
```

Now, I have rpmb available on my system:

```
[root@localhost peeyush]# sudo find / -name "*rpmb*"
/usr/lib64/librpmbuild.so.3
/usr/lib64/librpmbuild.so
/usr/lib64/librpmbuild.so.3.3.1
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/rpm/_rpmb.so
/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/rpm/_rpmb.cpython-34m.so
```

Though mock has nothing to do with modules installed on the system, but as I can see getting rpmb is possible for chroot env. Can anyone please tell me why am I getting this error? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a RPM bug. See:
 https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1236493